# My ID's have been changed, how can i stop it?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to do something simple, i think, let me explain:

I have an BPMS software where a send an e-mail at the end of the process, this e-mail is an HTML page that i created, inside the HTML page we have some identifying codes that get a field value from an previously form, some strings. The problem is, when i transfer that value to the HTML page, obviously the "Enter" key doesn't work like the "br" tag, so i made a simple javascript to replace the "enter" for the "br". It worked, but when i send the e-mail my ID is changed and they put an "x_" prefix, so there goes my question.

Can i stop it or there is some other way to do it?

The code is below:

```
 <p id="informacoes">
                        TEST
                        TEST
                    </p>

<script>
    var strMessege = document.getElementById('informacoes');
    strMessege.innerHTML = strMessege.innerHTML.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
</script>
```

Comment: What software are you using?  Could you just add the "x_" prefix in your code?

Comment: Can you give an example of your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your end goal here is to retain original line breaks present in the source code. I think your best bet would be to address this using CSS.

Take a look at the CSS property `white-space`, [MDN: white-space property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

By default, CSS collapses white space (e.g. multiple non-breaking ("regular") spaces, tabs, and newlines) into, effectively, a single regular space. In your example, the line breaks that you see in the source code are being collapsed and so they will not be rendered by the browser or email client.

Try using CSS to set a different `white-space` property, like

```css
#informacoes {
  white-space: pre-line;
/* depending on your use case, 
   a different value might work better */
}
```

Property values other than `white-space: normal` (which is the default) will change whether and how white space, including new lines, are collapsed when rendering from the source code to the screen.